# How can you replace column values using if/else statements in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Just to preface this I have very little SQL experience. I know how to do all these transformations in C++ and Python.

I have a column within a table that has a couple of different values that need to be selected and altered to other things using simple if-else logic.

| col1-intial | col1-final |
| --- | --- |
| ExampleVal1 | finalValue1 |
| ExampleVal2 | finalValue1 |
| ExampleVal3 | finalValue1 |
| ExampleVal4 | finalValue2 |
| ExampleValN | finalValueN |

```
select col1,
case(
when col1 == 'val1' or col1 == 'val2' or col1 == 'val3'
then col1 = replace(col1,('val1','val2','val3'), 'finalval1' )
else
when col1 == 'val4'
then col1 = replace(col1, 'val4', 'finalval2')
...
else
when colN == 'valN'
then col1 = replace(col1, 'valn', 'finalvalN')

),
select col2,
...
select coli
from tab1
```

pseudo-code

```
select column1 from table1
if column value is value1,value2,value3
set column value equal to final-value1
else if column value is value4
set column value is equal to final-value2
else if column value is value N
set column value equal to final-valueN
```

Comment: Please ad a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: That `CASE` expression doesn't make any sense. `CASE` returns a scalar value, yet you seem to be trying to inject some kind of `WHERE`  the query prior to the `FROM` (which isn't where the `WHERE` goes). Also T-SQL doesn't use `==` or `||`; where did you get this syntax from as it seems you've been reading some quite wrong literature. Along with the sample data, and expected results, a clear description of what you're trying to achieve nwill really help, as the code above doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: Sample data is added, and instead of == should I be using is?

Comment: *`replace(col1, 'valn', 'finalval2')`* what's `'valn'`? If you say **col1 = 'val4'** how can it be **'valn'**?

Comment: My bad it was supposed to be val4

Answer (score 0):

If you need it as `select` you can do it like:

```sql
select col1-intial = col1, col1-final = case 
    when col1 in('val1','val2','val3') then 'finalval1'
    when col1 = 'val4' then 'finalval2'
    when col1 = 'valN' then 'finalvalN'
    end
from table
```

If you need to `update` your table you should just change `select` to `set` with just the col1-final.